# Como receber vários parâmetros no evento OnNavigatedTo windowsPhone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Boa noite estou usando o `frame.navigate` para mudar de páginas e passar um objeto como parâmetro no windowsphone até ai tudo tranquilo minha duvida é como faço para passar outro parâmetro que vem de outra pagina sem ocorrer problema. Esta ocorrendo um erro pois ao tentar passar outro parâmetro ele cai no primeiro e trava gostaria de saber como fazer o tratamento para diferenciar os parâmetros enviados de paginas diferentes. Exemplo

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e){
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if(e. tratamento que estou em duvida = objeto cliente){          

        Cliente clienteRecebido = (Cliente)e.Parameter;
        tbIdCliente.Text = Convert.ToString(clienteRecebido.idCliente);
        tbCliente.Text = clienteRecebido.razao;
        tbDataPedido.Text = "01/01/2015";

    }else if(e.tratamento que estou em duvida = objeto produto){
           //classe protudo e seus atributos etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi direito a sua dúvida, você quer passar dois objetos pelo navigated to?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar o NavigationService? Mas dá uma olhada aqui: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5/passing-parameters-during-navigation-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp usando lista

Comment: Vou tentar exemplificar pra vê se consigo  explicar melhor o problema

Comment: Vou tentar exemplificar pra vê se consigo  explicar melhor o problema. Tem uma tela principal com dois botões um botão vai pra uma tela de clientes e outro botão vai pra tela de produtos. Ao clicar no botão pra ir pra tela de clientes aparece uma lista com os clientes para o usuário escolher ao clicar nessa lista eu retor no para tela principal passando como parâmetro um objeto cliente. Depois vou escolher os produtos clico no botão de pesquisa de produto que me leva para uma tela que tem um list com os produtos e esse list ao ser clicado no item retorna para tela principal com um obj de param

Comment: Meu problema esta ao receber esse segundo parâmetro pq sei que tem que haver um tratamento para identificar que tipo de parâmetro estou recebendo mais sei fazer esse tratamento. No meu caso NavigationService não esta dando certo pra essa versão que estou desenvolvendo Leornado já tentei e não deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu imagino, pelo que você descreveu nos comentários, que você está retornando os parâmetros corretamente no retorno da página, para tratar, o que você deve fazer é o seguinte:

```
if (e.Parameter.GetType() == typeof(Cliente)) {
    //Faz o que deve ser feito para o cliente
} else if (e.Parameter.GetType() == typeof(Produto)) {
    //Faz o que deve ser feito com o produto
} else {
    //Recebeu um tipo não esperado
}
```

Espero que isso resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Bom dia Felipe. Era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo testei e funcionou do jeito que eu estava esperando. Muito obrigado.